# How can I debug Python modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, python-module

While I was working on [How to list files inside tar in AWS S3 without downloading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086604/how-to-list-files-inside-tar-in-aws-s3-without-downloading-it) I wanted to debug [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) to see what was happening. I'm running VSCode on Ubuntu 18.04 and I found I could just download [tarfile.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tarfile.py) to my local directory and step into the functions. That was great but then I realised it was using [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) so I downloaded and saved [gzip.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/gzip.py) locally as well. But that didn't work. Is there a better/proper way of doing this?

Comment: You already have those files. They come with Python.

Comment: But I couldn't step into them while debugging.

Comment: Are you using pdb or what?

Comment: Whatever VSCode uses by default.